# getView() is not working as i supposed

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am going to develop a APP where i am using customize alert dialog. Data have come from database to this alert-dialog.

```
 menu_to_showdialogCursor = dh.rawQuery("SELECT _id ,item_name,Item_cost FROM order_customer WHERE item_name LIKE ? AND Item_cost LIKE ?", new String[]{"%","%"});
 OrderListAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderListAdapter(MainScreen.this,menu_to_showdialogCursor );
 orderList.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
```

ABove line is calling my Adapter class.Now i ma going to show my getView() in adapter class

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    OrderViewHolder orderViewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        orderViewHolder = new OrderViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_list_row, null);
            orderViewHolder.setTvTitle((TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.orderTitle));
            orderViewHolder.setTvPrice((TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.orderPrice));
            orderViewHolder.setIvDelete((ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.deleteOrder));


        convertView.setTag(orderViewHolder);

    } else {
        orderViewHolder = (OrderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (position != 0)

    {
  System.out.println(" value of position  :"+position);  
  List lit = new ArrayList();
  List litp = new ArrayList();

 // System.out.println(" value of postion of cursor  : ");
  OrderViewHolder odr_obj = null;
        if (oStarterCursor.moveToFirst()) {     
            do{    
                odr_obj = new OrderViewHolder();
             title = oStarterCursor.getString(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("item_name"));
            System.out.println("value of title   :"+title);

            lit.add(title);
             price = oStarterCursor.getString(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("Item_cost"));  
            System.out.println("value of price   :"+price);
            litp.add(price);
            }while(oStarterCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        //  _id = oStarterCursor.getInt(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            if (title != null) {
                title = title.trim();  
                Iterator it = lit.iterator();    
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    int i =0;
                    //System.out.println(" data iterator "+it.next().toString());
                    String test =it.next().toString();
                    System.out.println(" iterator vavue :"+test);
                    orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setText(test);   

                }

                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextColor(R.color.black);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextSize(12);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setGravity(   
                        Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);    
            }   
            if (price != null) {
                price = price.trim();
                orderViewHolder.getTvPrice().setText(price + ".00");
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextColor(R.color.black);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextSize(12);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setGravity(
                        Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            }
            //_id = oStarterCursor.getInt(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));




        //convertView.setTag(R.id.orderTitle, _id);
        if (orderViewHolder.getIvDelete() != null) {
            //orderViewHolder.getIvDelete().setTag(R.id.orderTitle, _id);
        }

    }
    return convertView;}
```

Problem is that in my data base there is two row as in below image..[image]

But in my alert dialog only showing one row twice. I did not get where is logical mistake.For conveniences i am going to show my screen-shot[image]

So Where is problem i can't get please some body help me take out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because you are using getView wrong, getView does not just get called once it gets called many times. you are looping through your cursor each time getView is called so you are only displaying the last item in the cursor after you loop through your 2 lists.

if you are getting data from a cursor you should be using `SimpleCursorAdapter` and then override `bindView` and just use the cursor variable in the method each time its called

**Edit**

basically along the lines of this

```
oStarterCursor.moveToPosition(position);
orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setText(oStarterCursor.getString(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("item_name")));
```

is all you need to get the data really

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your line :

```
if (position != 0)
```

The first line of an adapter is 0 so it will not set the data for the first line of data.